# Why I get 'No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains' error?

Tags: java, android, sdk

I installed Android SDK, but got error message below

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi

Do you know what does it mean?

Comment: Have you solve this problem? I'm facing same problem please help me.